# loading external html file using jquery and accessing it content

Tags: php, jquery, loading

I need to access some `TD` values in a `TABLE` that is in another `HTML` file. I am not really sure what way helps me get a working solution for this. Currently I want to access it using jquery. All I imagine for solving this issue is to load the whole external HTML file into a DIV in my main file and seek through the TDs to find my favorite one and print its content to my main TABLE TD. I do not seem to be able to figure it out. please help me with this!
My main PHP file:

```
<?php
...
...
$loading_transmitter = $_POST['transmitter']; 
?> 
<script>  
$("#result").load('<?php echo $loading_transmitter; ?>',function(){
    var main_proc_temp = $(table:nth-child(2).tr:nth-child(1).td:nth-child(3)).text();#table loaded from the external file
    alert(main_proc_temp);#it should alert: "OK" but alets: "Undefined"
});
</script>
```

Is the content of the loaded file available this way? Because after loading it on the page (which goes well), I checked the source code and found out that the `result` div is yet empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have `tr and td class` so remove the `.` from the `selectors` then check.

Also you should `find` your `table` in your `response`like,

like,

```
$("#result").load('<?php echo $loading_transmitter; ?>',function(data){
    var main_proc_temp = $(data).find('table:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)').text();
    alert(main_proc_temp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, can you not write these values to a database as they change and access them that way?

Comment: well, the main problem is currently ACCESSING THESE VALUES, the values are in a built-in HTML file that are readonly for some communication transmitters!